# Stuck on loading a cog and being able to send a message from it

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm quite new to python and discord.py. I am trying to create a discord bot.
My first attempts were a success, and now I want to split it into multiple files.

But, I am really struggling on getting my cog to load and run properly.

Using this code to load the cog in my **main.py**

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

async def load_cogs():
    # List of cogs to load on start
    print(f'Cogs: Start Loading')
    cog_list = ['cogs.notify']
    for cog in cog_list:
        try:
            await bot.load_extension(cog)
            print(f'Cogs: Loaded - {cog}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Cogs: Failed to load - {cog}: {e}')
    print(f'Cogs: Finished loading.')

# Once online, run
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Machine Spirit: Start awakening [{client.user}]')
    await load_cogs()
    await setup_application_events(client) #Enables event based actions
    await setup_application_commands(bot, client) #Sets up commands to be synced
    print(f'Machine spirit: Awakened. praise the Omnissiah!')

# Run the bot
client.run(BOT_TOKEN, log_handler=handler)
```

I keep getting the error:`'CommandTree' object has no attribute 'load_extension'`

The same happens if I change my load function to use `client.load_extension(cog)`

So, upon reading the documentation, and looking at online examples and tutorials, I attempted this change in my **main.py**

```
# Defining client intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
memorius = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None, intents=intents) #change

async def load_cogs():
    # List of cogs to load on start
    print(f'Cogs: Start Loading')
    cog_list = ['cogs.notify']
    for cog in cog_list:
        try:
            await memorius.load_extension(cog) #change
            print(f'Cogs: Loaded - {cog}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Cogs: Failed to load - {cog}: {e}')
    print(f'Cogs: Finished loading.')
```

now my cog loads, but whenever I attempt to execute the code in my **notify.py**
I get this error in my logs:

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<Loop._loop() done, defined at /home/jelle/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py:200> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jelle/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 264, in _loop
    raise exc
  File "/home/jelle/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 239, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jelle/Documents/repo/Memorius/test/cogs/notify.py", line 43, in notify
    invitation = await channel.send(f'**Attention <@&{PING_ROLE_ID}>!**\n The administratum has requested each of you to react with your possible attendance.\n :one: Saturday {formatted_next_saturday} \n :two: Sunday {formatted_next_sunday} \n :x: if you are a heretic.')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

For reference, here is my **notify.py / cog**

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import datetime
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

#load ENV
GUILD_ID = os.getenv('GUILD_ID')
ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID = int(os.getenv('ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID'))
NOTIFY_DAY = int(os.getenv('NOTIFY_DAY'))
NOTIFY_HOUR = int(os.getenv('NOTIFY_HOUR'))
PING_ROLE_ID = os.getenv('PING_ROLE_ID')

async def setup(memorius):
    await memorius.add_cog(Notify(memorius))

class Notify(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, memorius):
        self.memorius = memorius
        self.notify.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.notify.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(hours=1)
    async def notify(self):
        print(f'Notify Cog Started')
        #If the target day and hour is met, send a poll in a prespecified channel
        current_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
        channel = self.memorius.get_channel(ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID)
        notify_Day = current_Time.weekday()  
        if notify_Day == NOTIFY_DAY:
            notify_Time = current_Time.hour

            next_saturday = current_Time + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
            next_saturday = next_saturday.replace(hour=11, minute=30)
            formatted_next_saturday = next_saturday.strftime("%d-%m-%Y at %H:%M")
            
            next_sunday = current_Time + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
            next_sunday = next_sunday.replace(hour=11, minute=30)
            formatted_next_sunday = next_sunday.strftime("%d-%m-%Y at %H:%M")
            
            if notify_Time == NOTIFY_HOUR:
                invitation = await channel.send(f'**Attention <@&{PING_ROLE_ID}>!**\n The administratum has requested each of you to react with your possible attendance.\n :one: Saturday {formatted_next_saturday} \n :two: Sunday {formatted_next_sunday} \n :x: if you are a heretic.')
                await invitation.add_reaction('1️⃣')
                await invitation.add_reaction('2️⃣')
                await invitation.add_reaction('❌')
```

I know for a fact that my **notify.py** worked when I had everything in 1 big file, but after the split I just cannot seem to either A: load the cog or B: send the message.

From my understanding, the Client and Command trunk simply won't take the cogs being added, but the correct bot class that adds the cogs, doesn't have the ability to take data from the messages?

I'm completely stuck and any help or pointers is appreciated greatly, Thanks in advance!

Any workarounds or fixes that I am missing? I've been looking for hours.

Full bot source code (big file): https://github.com/Jelle-Kuipers/Memorius/tree/dev
Attempted splitting source code: https://github.com/Jelle-Kuipers/Memorius/tree/reorg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while this is technically not an answer, but the solution I found to get the bot to atleast work currently is:

Importing and calling the class while passing the Client in the main.py file, as can be seen here:

```
from cogs.notify_cog import Notify

#Once online, run
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Awakening machine spirit of: {client.user}')
    Notify(client) #Load Cog (THIS IS NOT HOW YOU LOAD COGS BUT I JUST CANT GET IT TO WORK AS A NORMAL COG!)
    setup_application_events(client) #Enables event based actions
    await setup_application_commands(bot, client) #Sets up commands to be synced
    print(f'Machine spirit awakened, praise the Omnissiah!')
client.run(BOT_TOKEN, log_handler=handler)
```

Not intended use of cogs, but this is the only way I managed to get it to work.

I'll revisit cogs at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

The error you provided indicates that you might pass in a wrong channel id.
Check it by copying the id the paste it into discord like this: <#THE_ID>

Also for loading cogs I use this snippet:

```
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(PATH_TO_COGS):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            i += 1
            cog_name = filename[:-3]
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog_name}')
    print(f"Loaded {i} cogs")
```

And I just put this into the `on_ready` event. But if yours works it is fine too. When you have multiple cogs, with this you can easily load them and don't have to update your cog list manually.

Comment: Hey, so while testing with this theory, in my server <#ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID> Correctly returns the #general channel.

When testing this line: ```channel= self.memorius.get_channel(ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID)```

I attempted to print channel with: ```print(f'{channel}```, which returned None

Attempting this same method on my big file where the line reads:
```channel = client.get_channel(ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID)```
the print returns ```general``` which is the channel name.

So it seems I need to pass both the client and the bot into the cog? Kinda stumped on how to achieve that

Comment: Apologies for bad formatting, not quite sure why my ENTERS arent being saved :(